# How Do You Program the SR04 Ultrasonic Sensor?

Tags: mobile-robot, arduino, sensors, wheeled-robot, ultrasonic-sensors

Dear Robotics Community,

I am participating in a Robotics tourney that will start in a few weeks. The challenge I signed up for is to deliver and dump ping pong balls to a box. I already have my robot and the ball container built, but I need some help with coding it.

I just need help coding an SR04 ultrasonic sensor for my Arduino robot. I want it so that when it senses the box in front of it, the robot turns on a motor and stops when the box is a certain distance away from the robot. I also want it to back up and go back to its starting position when it is done delivering the payload. I was told by my coach that a "boolean variable" would do the job, but I also do not know how to program this.

Thank you!

(Here is the robot platform I am using: https://www.elegoo.com/product/elegoo-uno-project-smart-robot-car-kit-v1-0/)

Answer (score 1):

Did you try the [newPing](https://github.com/PaulStoffregen/NewPing) library ?